# AC circuit capacitor voltage drop

Tags: voltage, ac

Suppose we have this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBo0Xg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Z = 4-3j

I = V/Z = 1<0/5<36 = 0.2< -36 A

But when I use Ohm's law on the capacitor i get this which doesn't make any sense:

Vc = I*Zc = 0.2< -36* -3j = 0.2< -36 *3< -90  = 0.6< -126.

Any help appreciated

Comment: You have an error in the impedance: Z=1-3j, unless the error is in the schematic. Please correct your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we know that:

$$\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{C}}=\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\cdot\frac{\hat{\text{u}}\exp\left(\theta\text{j}\right)}{\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}\tag1$$

Assuming that the \$1\space\text{V}\$ is the amplitude of the voltage-source, we get:

$$\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{C}}=\frac{1}{\text{j}\cdot4\cdot750\cdot10^{-3}}\cdot\frac{1\exp\left(0\text{j}\right)}{1+\frac{1}{\text{j}\cdot4\cdot750\cdot10^{-3}}}\tag2$$

So, the function in the time domain will be:

$$\text{V}_\text{C}\left(t\right)=\left|\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{C}}\right|\sin\left(\omega t+\arg\left(\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{C}}\right)\right)\tag3$$

And you will find:

$$\left|\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{C}}\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\approx0.316228\space\text{V}\space\space\space\wedge\space\space\space\arg\left(\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{C}}\right)=-\arctan(3)\approx-1.24905\space\text{rad}\tag4$$

Comment: Why bother with polar notation for the impedance, while using the rule for complex conjugates makes solving this much easier?: 1/Z=(4+3j)/25

Answer (score 0):

By l = V/Z we get the magnitude and phase angle of the total current in the circuit.

By V(c) = I * Z(c) we get the magnitude and phase angle of the voltage across the capacitor.

By your calculations current in the network leads the voltage across the capacitor by 90 degree.

Completely make sense.